# Does marathon-lb support websockets?

Tags: load-balancing, marathon

I'm looking to run websockets in marathon tasks (containers) and would like to know if marathon-lb supports the load-balancing of sockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marathon-LB does support websockets.

See [this answer](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon-lb/issues/105#issuecomment-221335568) from the maintainer.